# Python regex does not match line start

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with some data:

```
... 
DATA_ARRAY Some[] =
{
...
};
```

and I have a python 2.7 regex like this:

```
regx = re.compile("^DATA_ARRAY Some\[\].*?};", re.DOTALL)
regmatch = re.search(regx, data)
print regmatch.group(0)
```

The problem is that the regex does not match anything (regmatch is None). If I remove the ^ then it matches just fine.

What am I doing incorrectly here? I would like to add the line beginning search symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` checks for start of the string.. add `re.MULTILINE` flag.

```
regx = re.compile("^DATA_ARRAY Some\[\].*?};", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [modifier `^`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) forces your regex engine to match the regex from start of string. and since your string doesn't start with `DATA_ARRAY` it returns `None`.

And as @nanny mentioned If you also want it to match the start of each line, use `re.MULTILINE` flag :

```
regx = re.compile("^DATA_ARRAY Some\[\].*?};", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Indeed. If you also want it to match the start of each line, use `re.MULTILINE`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

Comment: This answer is correct, `^` matches the start of the string, or the start of a line in case `re.MULTILINE` is set. So, depending if `DATA_ARRAY` is always at the start of a new line in the string, you need to get rid of the caret from the pattern or add the `re.MULTILINE` argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `re.MULTILINE` flag it should work.

This will make the flags look like `re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL`

Comment: I actually tried to change the re.DOTALL to re.MULTILINE but it still behaves the same way.

Comment: You will need to combine them, replacing wouldn't work as you need the dot to match other newlines. [Python documentation on re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)